# My package from Python work partially on some Windows

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, cx-freeze, windows-server-2019

I. I wrote a program in Python, with a tkinter GUI. Then I packaged it in msi with cx_freeze. My package installs perfectly on Windows 10 and 7, and works very well. But on Windows server 2019 it only works halfway. I use a lot of libraries and I do multi-threading. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: run program in console/terminal (in Windows Server 2019) to see error messages - it may show what libraries it needs to work correctly. And then add these libraries manully to setup.py in cx_freeze

Comment: Thank, but it's GUI program. my program runs fine and it doesn't generate any errors. It works well on Windows 10 and 7. Under Windows server 2019, it displays a progress bar when I click on a button and execute actions on a remote ELK server. But when I click on another button, nothing happens, whereas it should also display a progress bar and execute actions on another remote server...

Comment: first you could run it in console/terminal to see if it doesn't display error message - even if it is GUI program. It is only way to see errors. You can also use `print()` in functions to see values in variables and which part of code is executed. This way you can see in which moment it freeze. But to see text from `print()` you have run it in console/terminal. It is primitive but useful method to debug program.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that it doesn't freeze.

Comment: But I can make a version that redirects the logs to the console. That's a good idea.

Comment: I rewrote my program with prints in the function that doesn't work. Unfortunately, even if you launch the application from powershell, the prints don't display in the terminal...

Comment: if print doesn't display then this function is not executed. Problem can be before before this function is executed. You could also add `print()` at the beginning of script to see if it will print in first line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: My function creates a directory with a txt file where it logs. This directory is created in "users\mylogin\.myapp". Under Windows 7 and Windows 10, no problems. Under Windows Server 2019, my application is not allowed to create this directory. That's what was blocking my function... Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you are going to be running on multiple platforms like this I would write in error handling anywhere it most likely can occur. So you get popups when things fail.